# C++ STL map not recognizing key

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have this code, CBString is just a string class I use for some processing

```
  char * scrummyconfigure::dosub(strtype input)
  {
    CBString tstring;
    tstring = input;
    uint begin;
    uint end;

    begin = tstring.findchr('$');
    end = tstring.findchr('}',begin);        

    CBString k = tstring.midstr(begin+2,end-2); // this is BASE
    strtype vname = (strtype) ((const unsigned char*)k);
    strtype bvar = (strtype) "BASE";
    assert(strcmp(bvar,vname) == 0); // this never fails
    // theconf is just a struct with the map subvars
    // subvars is a map<const char *, const char *>
    out(theconf->subvars[bvar]); // always comes up with the value
    out(theconf->subvars[vname]); // always empty

    uint size = end - begin;
    tstring.remove(begin, size);

    return (const char *)tstring; // it's OKAY! it's got an overload that does things correctly
    //inline operator const char* () const { return (const char *)data; } <-- this is how it is declared in the header of the library
  }
```

Why is it that the strcmp always says the strings are the same, but only the variable I declared as bvar returns anything?

Comment: I'm a bit uneasy about this: `(const unsigned char*)k`. At least using `static_cast` would assure me it's safe (assuming it compiles).

Comment: I understand, however, the class CBString has an overloaded (const char *) cast, where it sets it up to gather the actual bytes instead of a c++ class. Unless you mean something else? And why the static cast?

Comment: This code is definitely scary.  You've got a homerolled string representation (probably a raw pointer type, implying lots of scary leaks), a method called "dosub", lower case class names, and an important (presumably global) variable whose name begins with "the".

Comment: `static_cast` will choose an appropriate conversion operator if one exists in this case. C-style casts get you the result any way they can.  There's no way to tell from the C style casts if that's safe, but with `static_cast`, as long as the conversion operator is ok, we know it's not doing anything crazy. You also have a `const unsigned char *` conversion in one area, and a `const char *` in another (the one you added the note to), which you're returning as non-const.

Comment: Wug: got it, I'm for sure not the best at housekeeping, and this is the first "real" project I've worked on in C++. the rest of the code /r/nosleep worthy :)

Comment: @alexhairyman it's going to die a horrible unmaintenanceble death if you don't give it a bit of refactoring love and some design decision changes.

Comment: I'm hoping to really clean up the code before I start to promote it in the community I wrote it for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming `strtype` is defined in the following way:

```
typedef char * strtype
```

Your issue is that you're assuming that vname and bvar have the same value, where in reality, they have different values that each point to a block of memory that contains identical data.

`std::map` is dumbly comparing them with ==, and I bet you'd find that if you compared them with ==, you would get false, as expected.  Why exactly arent you using the `std::string` class?

Edit: I rewrote your method to be less scary:

```
// implied using namespace std;
string ScrummyConfigure::removeVariableOrSomething(string tstring)
{
    uint begin; // I'll assume uint is a typedef to unsigned int
    uint end;

    begin = tstring.find('$', 0);
    end = tstring.find('}', begin);        

    string vname = tstring.substr(begin + 2, end - 2); // this is supposedly BASE
    assert(vname == "BASE"); // this should be true if vname actually is BASE

    out(this->conf->subvars[bvar]);  // wherever theconf used to be, its now a member
    out(this->conf->subvars[vname]); // of ScrummyConfigure and its been renamed to conf

    uint size = end - begin;
    tstring.erase(begin, size);

    return tstring; // no casting necessary
}
```

Comment: Spot on, except for "std::map is dumbly comparing them with ==". I expect map to compare with == whatever I choose as the key. :)

Comment: maybe I'm reading that wrong, but it doesn't seem to make any sense.  consider revising?

Comment: I'm using it to do makefile style macro replacements, and it started to get ugly with all the .c_str() in there :D. I could do that, but really, then I would have to put a lot more strings in places where they may not need them. But if that is the only way I guess I'll have to go with it, it makes sense what you're saying though, those are really just 2 different addresses, not values.

Comment: I'm just saying if I make a map from pointers to something else, I want the map to compare the pointers with equality when querying for a key, not to test what they point to.

Comment: @alexhairyman if you want to keep pointers as keys, you can set-up a custom comparator. See atomicinf's answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore and Wug, `std::map` uses `<` not `==`.

Comment: Wug, Is it better to use `this` rather than just using the variable? (Is that a huge NoNo beginners mistake?). And thank you for the code.

Comment: `this` was only for emphasis that it is now a member of the class, since while omitting it is legal, it won't compile if its not a member.  It's a style thing.  I tend to leave it out because it makes for lots and lots of extra typing.  Also, if you declare a local variable with a name that conflicts with a member variable, use of `this` differentiates between them.

Answer (score 5):

> //subvars is a `map<const char *, const char *>`

The key of this map isn't a string per-say, but a memory address. The corresponding check would be

```
assert( bvar == vname);
```

which will probably fail. You'll need to change the key type to a string class (either `std::string` or `CBString` to meaningfully use the map.

Answer (score 5):

Just because the strings are the same doesn't mean that std::map will treat them as the same key. That depends on the Compare class that is used by the std::map, which defaults to `less<KeyType>` - which yields the same result as applying the less-than operator.

You can define a class that defines `operator()` to do a proper comparison on your strtypes and pass that as your third template argument when defining your std::map. Or, as suggested, use std::string as your strtype.